# T-SQL throw error if length is not equals

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to make a stored procedure for SQL Server 2016 to insert MD5 hashes to a table. I would like to check the length of the input, so I can throw an error if the hash is not 32 (or 34 characters).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_insert_imagestore
    @HashStr NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @NewId BIGINT OUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF LEFT(@HashStr, 2) = '0x' 
    BEGIN
        IF LEN(@HashStr) <> 34
        BEGIN
            ;THROW 50001, 'The HASH string must be a valid MD5 HASH!', 1;
        END
    ELSE
        IF LEN(@HashStr) <> 32
        BEGIN
            ;THROW 50002, 'The HASH string must be a valid MD5 HASH!', 1;
        END
    END
...
END
GO
```

The problem here is the error massages won't activate, even If I specify less or more then 32 or 34 characters. What am I missing?

The code calling in SSMS is

```
DECLARE @NewId bigint
EXECUTE [dbo].[usp_insert_imagestore] 
  '7815696ECBF1C96E6894B779456D330E000000000000000000000000'
  ,@NewId OUTPUT
GO

select * from ImageStore;
```

This should raise an error, shouldn't it?

Comment: Well, the obvious would be if the hash doesn't start with `0x`, which you haven't explicitly stated as having been ruled out.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I used an `ELSE`, in which case I check length=32.

Comment: could you show the calling code? execute the procedure in SSMS too, to check

Comment: If I correctly understand you, add `END` before `ELSE` and `BEGIN` after `ELSE` and check.

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you use? On first glance I would say, that the error should be fired for Length 32 as well, since your first "if length <> 34" would fire... same other way round I just tested it and it fires allways. Judging by your description: is it possible, that your data is missing the 0x at the beginning?

Comment: @Tyron78 I checked it, I called the code I posted and It won't raise an error.

Comment: @Rokuto `Incorrect syntax near 'END'.` Else shouldn't need an END before it I think

Comment: Obligatory comment about MD5 being broken (of course it depends what you are using those hashes for....)

Comment: @MitchWheat No worries, it only stores file hashes for products :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ELSE` will "fire" when your `@HashStr` starts with `0x` and length of this variable is equal to 34. You have to change code to this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_insert_imagestore
    @HashStr NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @NewId BIGINT OUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF LEFT(@HashStr, 2) = '0x' 
    BEGIN
        IF LEN(@HashStr) <> 34
        BEGIN
            ;THROW 50001, 'The HASH string must be a valid MD5 HASH!', 1;
        END
    END /*<-- Add this*/
    ELSE
    BEGIN /*<-- Add this*/
        IF LEN(@HashStr) <> 32
        BEGIN
            ;THROW 50002, 'The HASH string must be a valid MD5 HASH!', 1;
        END
    END
...
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @HashStr NVARCHAR(100) = '0x12345678901234567890123456789012';

IF LEFT(@HashStr, 2) = '0x' AND LEN(@HashStr) <> 34 
  BEGIN
    ;THROW 50001, 'The HASH string must be a valid MD5 HASH!', 1;
  END
ELSE IF LEFT(@HashStr, 2) != '0x' AND LEN(@HashStr) <> 32
  BEGIN
    ;THROW 50002, 'The HASH string must be a valid MD5 HASH!', 1;
  END
```

Comment: If the input starts with `0x` the length should be 34, otherwise 32.

Comment: OK, guess this wasn't mentioned in th eOP? However, I modified the answer accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

You need `END` before the `ELSE` and `BEGIN` after it, otherwise your `ELSE` applies to `IF LEN(@HashStr) <> 34`